# Con la suma funciona pero con la multiplicacion no

Tags: python

Estoy intentando hacer que los números del 1 al 1000 se multipliquen pero al hacerlo no funciona apesar de que con una suma si funciona

```
lista = []
o = 0
for i in range(o, 1001):
    lista.append(i)


def multipicar(lista):
    x = 0
    for n in lista:
        x *= n
    return x

def sumando(lista):
    suma = 0
    for number in lista:
        suma += number
    return suma

print(sumando(lista))
print(multipicar(lista))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

si partes con `x` en cero, cualquier cosa que le multipliques te dará cero.

Solución: partir de uno.

```
def multipicar(lista):
    x = 1
    for n in lista:
        x *= n
    return x
```

Comment: Ademas la lista empieza en 0 y tambien deberia empezar en 1

Comment: @Fedex7501. La lista puede tener cualquier valor (incluso cero). Lo importante es que la función da el resultado correcto.

Comment: Sí pero OP dijo "Estoy intentando hacer que los números del 1 al 1000 se multipliquen", pero está multiplicando del 0 al 1000

Comment: @Fedex7501. Cierto. Sólo me enfoque en un solo problema. Puedes agregar tu propia respuesta señalando el caso.